# How do you set the default value for Django's 'on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT'

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

In the example below, how--and where--do you set the default value?

`author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [`SET_DEFAULT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_DEFAULT) to work, [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#default) should be used in the `ForeignKey` declaration:

```
author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)
```

In this case, whatever is set as `default` will be used when the related object is deleted.

EDIT:
As pointed out by @MojixCoder and @Ersain, in this example you need to set `null=True` otherwise deleting the instance of the ForeignKey will cause `IntegrityError` to be raised.

Comment: this is only possible if `null=True` [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL).

Comment: when specifying default as None, does this make the field nullable automatically? or I should declare it explicitly?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#null you can check default in doc. it is false you have to set it explicitly

Comment: Tested this. `null=True` is needed if default is `None`. Great catch thanks